# Find and move string to end of line

Tags: awk, sed

I need to move a specific string to the end of the line, but I completely don't know how. Here is example:

```
:88:Some text/Some text/Some text/**TEXT TO MOVE**/Some textSome text/Some text/Some textSome text/

:29:Some textSome text/**TEXT TO MOVE**/Some textSome text/Some text/Some text/

...
```

Each line differs in length and "Some text" between slashes is different in every line.
Each line ends with "/" always and starts with ":xx:" where x - some digits.

Is there anybody who can help me?

Comment: I think you need to key in on the "between slashes". What about parsing that line into individual components, using the slashes as the delimiters. Then you could put the components back together in a different order.

Comment: do the number of `/` either before or after `**TEXT TO MOVE**` vary with each line as well or is there a typo in your second line (`:29:SometextSometext/`)? Is `**TEXT TO MOVE**` always the same?

Comment: I don't know what is happend, someone wrote a great answer and a few minutes ago the answer was disappeared. Everything is working right now. Thanks a lot!

Here is the answer:

sed 's!(/TEXT TO MOVE/)(.*)/!\2\1!' input

Comment: That answer does NOT look for a string, it looks for a regular expression which I assume is why the poster removed the `*`s from it so it wouldn't appear as complicated as it really is. It is not possible with sed to create a robust solution which will search for a string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always have the same number of fields *to the right* of `**TEXT TO MOVE**`, you can do this:

```
$ echo -e ':88:Some text/Some text/Some text/**TEXT TO MOVE**/Some textSome text/Some text/Some textSome text/
:29:Some textSome text/**TEXT TO MOVE**/Some textSome text/Some text/Some text/' \
| awk -F'/' '
    {
      for (i = 1; i <= NF - 5; i++) { 
        printf("%s/", $i)
      }
      printf("%s/%s/%s/", $(NF - 3), $(NF - 2), $(NF - 1));
      print $(NF - 4) "/"
}'
:88:Some text/Some text/Some text/Some textSome text/Some text/Some textSome text/**TEXT TO MOVE**/
:29:Some textSome text/Some textSome text/Some text/Some text/**TEXT TO MOVE**/
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work no matter what RE meta-characters are included in the string being moved because it works on strings, not REs:

```
$ cat file
Some text/Some text/**TEXT TO MOVE**/Some text/Some text/
Some text/**TEXT TO MOVE**/Some textSome text/

$ awk -v str='**TEXT TO MOVE**' 's=index($0,str){$0 = substr($0,1,s-1) substr($0,s+length(str)) str }1' file
Some text/Some text//Some text/Some text/**TEXT TO MOVE**
Some text//Some textSome text/**TEXT TO MOVE**
```

Comment: nice approach! I assumed `**TEXT TO MOVE**` may not be constant. You might want to adjust your `subsrt` start and finish to avoid the double slash though. I would assume OP wants `/` to act as a field separator.

Comment: If the OP wants to add anything, he just needs to add it to `str`. Without expected output we're just guessing so no point us doing it.